# How to create my own method to calculate the difference between two dates in python not using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm Python beginner and I've created a method to calculate a difference between two dates using a reader from csv file with format `dd/mm/yyyy`. It works for me with this code

```
DATE_DEBUT= datetime.datetime(int(row[2][6:]), int(row[2][3:5]),int(row[2][:2]))
DATE_FIN= datetime.datetime(int(row[3][6:]), int(row[3][3:5]),int(row[3][:2]))
NB_JOURS_TT=(DATE_FIN-DATE_DEBUT).days+1
```

But it's slow. I want to create a method which take parametres days/month/year of start date and the days/months/year of end dates and return number of days.

Comment: How you try anything? first split datetime object to year, month, dat then try to find difference between years , then month, then days. consider leap year.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to write anything yourself that would be faster than using the built-in `datetime` module. If you insist, try writing the code to do it the way you would by hand. If you can't get it to work, _then_ come here and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method for parse date in a custom format.

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%d/%m/%Y')
d2 = datetime.strptime(row[3], '%d/%m/%Y')
delta = (d2 - d1).days
```